# Formatting values with AngularJs filters

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am writing a common control that will be used to format data inside a grid. It has 2 parameters that user can set:

- **filter** (string) that is used to format value
- **parameters** (any[]) that are used by the filter

In the code I am going to call ***$filter(filter)(value, ...)*** - here is my problem. How do I pass my parameters? Each filter can have from no parameters to who knows how many. So, is there a nice way to pass variable number of parameters in Angular? So far I did not run into a way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do:

```
$filter(filter).apply(this, parameters)
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I did not think about it.

Comment: In fact it does not work, I just did not catch it. One of my filters takes 2 parameters: a number and a boolean, So, my parameters array looks like [3, true]. Passing it as a second parameter to $filter does not work.

Comment: This is why you need to use apply, which is expecting an array of parameters for second argument.